# how to deny read access to git branch (with third party tools)

Tags: git

How can I deny read access to certain git versioned branches/files or folders with third party tools?

I know it's not possible with git itself, this has been asked over and over again, and the answer was always:
"You can't. You can only deny write access via git hooks."

I read that gerrit is able to such a thing because they have their own sshd and git deamon.

Background:

I want to host a coding event.
For each Task/Challenge participants will be able to clone a template and instructions (branch task1).
They can then modify the template and run it against a provided test-set.
When they decide to submit their work, they can push the code. A server side hook will compile the program,run it against another test-set (branch task1_tests) and return the achieved score to the committer. Furthermore the server will merge the users solution in another branch (task1_solutions). From that point on I want to allow the user to view the branches task1_tests and task1_solutions, so he's able to compare his solutions with the solutions of others. But while he's still working on his solution he shouldn't be able to clone those branches.

One solution would be to encrypt the branches I want to hide and return the decryption key together with his score in the commit response (See also: http://syncom.appspot.com/papers/git_encryption.txt).

Is there a nicer way to achieve the same?

Comment: If the answer "You can't" has been given over and over again, what logic implies that asking the question one more time would change the answer? You can certainly use third-party tools like `gerrit` (there are likely others as well), but `git` does not have such functionality, and given the mind-sets of the core developers/maintainers of `git`, it's probably not ever likely to have such functionality...

Comment: You're right, maybe I should append "with third party tools" to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create access control to git server with [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html). It can do that using ["partial-copies"](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#partial-copy) (or you can use separte repositories, just as the gitolite's partial copy).